# ReadFile !=0, lpNumberOfBytesRead=0 but offset is not at the end of the file

Tags: windows, winapi

We're struggling to understand the source of the following bug:

We have a call to "[ReadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile)" (Synchronous) that returns a non-zero value (success) but fills the lpNumberOfBytesRead parameter to 0. In theory, that indicates that the offset is outside the file but, in practice, that is not true. [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms679360) returns ERROR_SUCCESS(0).

The files in question are all on a shared network drive (Windows server 2016 + DFS, windows 8-10 clients, SMBv3). The files are used in shared mode. In-file locking (lockFileEx) is used to handle concurrent file access (we're just locking the first byte of the file before any read/write).

The handle used is not fresh: it isn't created locally in the functions but retrieved from a application-wide "file handle cache manager". This means that it could have been created (unused) some times ago. However, everything we did indicates the handle is valid at the moment of the call: GetLastError returns 0, [GetFileInformationByHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileinformationbyhandle) returns "true" and a valid structure.

The error is logged to a file that is located on the same file server as the problematic files.

We have done a lot of logging and testing around this issue. here are the additional facts we gathered:

- Most (but not all) of the problematic read happen at the very tail of the file: we're reading the last record. However, the read is still within the file GetlastError does not return ERROR_HANDLE_EOF. If the program is restarted, the same read with the same parameters works.
- The issue is not temporary: repeated calls yield the same result even if we let the program loop indefinitely. Restarting the program, however, does not automatically leads to the issue being raised again immediately.
- We are sure the offset if inside the file: we check the actual file pointer location after the failure and compare it with the expected value as well as the size of the file as reported by the OS: all matches across multiple retries.
- The issue only shows up randomly: there is no real pattern to the program working as expected and the program failing. It occurs a 2-4 times a day in our office (about 20 people).
- The issue does not only occurs in our network. we've seen the symptoms and the log entries in multiple locations although we have no clear view of the OS involved in these cases.

We just deployed a new version of the program that will attempt to re-open the file in case of failure but that is a workaround, not a fix: we need to understand what is happening here and I must admit that I found no rational explanation for it

Any suggestion about what could be the cause of this error or what other steps could be taken to find out will be welcome.

**Edit 2**
(In the light of keeping this clear, I removed the code: the new evidence gives a better explanation of the issue)

We managed to get a procmon trace while the problem was happening and we got the following sequence of events that we simply cannot explain:

[image: ProcMon captured lines]

Text version:

```
"Time of Day","Process Name","PID","Operation","Path","Result","Detail","Command Line"
"9:43:24.8243833 AM","wacprep.exe","33664","ReadFile","\\office.git.ch\dfs\Data\EURDATA\GIT18\JNLS.DTA","END OF FILE","Offset: 7'091'712, Length: 384, Priority: Normal","O:\WinEUR\wacprep.exe  /company:GIT18"
"9:43:24.8244011 AM","wacprep.exe","33664","QueryStandardInformationFile","\\office.git.ch\dfs\Data\EURDATA\GIT18\JNLS.DTA","SUCCESS","AllocationSize: 7'094'272, EndOfFile: 7'092'864, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False","O:\WinEUR\wacprep.exe  /company:GIT18"
```

(there are thousands of these logged since the application is in an infinite loop.)

As we understand this, the ReadFile call should succeed: the offset is well within the boundary of the file. Yet, it fails. ProcMon reports `END OF FILE`although I suspect it's just because ReadFile returned != 0 and reported 0 bytes read.

While the loop was running, we managed to unblock it by increasing the size of the file from a different machine:

```
"Time of Day","Process Name","PID","Operation","Path","Result","Detail","Command Line"
"9:46:58.6204637 AM","wacprep.exe","33664","ReadFile","\\office.git.ch\dfs\Data\EURDATA\GIT18\JNLS.DTA","END OF FILE","Offset: 7'091'712, Length: 384, Priority: Normal","O:\WinEUR\wacprep.exe  /company:GIT18"
"9:46:58.6204810 AM","wacprep.exe","33664","QueryStandardInformationFile","\\office.git.ch\dfs\Data\EURDATA\GIT18\JNLS.DTA","SUCCESS","AllocationSize: 7'094'272, EndOfFile: 7'092'864, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False","O:\WinEUR\wacprep.exe  /company:GIT18"
"9:46:58.7270730 AM","wacprep.exe","33664","ReadFile","\\office.git.ch\dfs\Data\EURDATA\GIT18\JNLS.DTA","SUCCESS","Offset: 7'091'712, Length: 384, Priority: Normal","O:\WinEUR\wacprep.exe  /company:GIT18"
```

Comment: and here i not view bug at all. `ReadFile` not fail - it return true. and we always need check actual Number Of Bytes Read. it can be less than `NumberOfBytesToRead`. the 0 also valid value which mean that nothing readed

Comment: [_"When a synchronous read operation gets to the end of a file, ReadFile returns TRUE and sets the variable pointed to by the lpNumberOfBytesRead parameter to zero."_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/testing-for-the-end-of-a-file). `GetLastError()` has no meaning when `ReadFile()` returns `TRUE` in synchronous mode.

Comment: Don't describe your code, add [mcve]. I suspect there is a misunderstanding about correct usage of `ReadFile`.

Comment: @zett42 - *When a synchronous read operation..* - this is not  true. this depend from - are `lpOverlapped != 0`. if `lpOverlapped == 0` - yes, return true and set `*lpNumberOfBytesRead = 0`, otherwise return false. but `lpOverlapped` can be not zero and in synchronous read operation too. so this or documentation or implementation bug

Comment: and really this is only user mode trick (special process for `STATUS_END_OF_FILE`), the `NtReadFile` free from this problem

Comment: @RbMm More reasons that we need [mcve]...

Comment: @KenWhite I understand that. I tried to emphasis the fact that the issue isn't with the code but with the way the OS works with the code: I have no idea what could cause such a behavior. You seem to focus on the fact that the code could be incorrect and I understand the point of view. It is difficult to create a sample, however, because the code in question has more than 20 years of (successful) history but I will try. Please give me a bit more time as I work to format the relevant code in a way that is readable and understandable.

Comment: There. I added the problematic code and some contextual code to show what we've tried to log to isolate the issue

Comment: I'd love it of the people who commented on this could either withdraw their negative votes or explain what else I could add to the question to make it more understandable. Thank you.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote after your addition of code. Thanks.

Comment: That's still far from a [mcve], which would ideally be a small console application that people can throw into their compiler *as is* to try and reproduce your issue.  We still don't know, how the above functions are called from your program. You should at least provide a `main()` function that calls these functions. While this might be difficult, I strongly believe that isolating the problem like this would improve your own understanding of the problem.

Comment: @zett42 I'm unconvinced that will really help but I'll create such a sample anyway. In the mean time, could I request that you assume that, as I tried to specify, the way I'm calling CreateFile, SeFilePointer and ReadFile is NOT incorrect and that you try to answer my question in that light ? I'm not (really) asking for debugging help but for possible explanation of the exposed symptoms?

Comment: OK, I think the test for success after the call to `EUR_gread()` is wrong. When EOF is reached, `ReadFile` returns success and the number of bytes read will be 0. But you still enter the else case, doing an invalid call to `GetLastError()`. After that, you enter the "retry" loop again, which makes no sense at all.

Comment: I think `EUR_gread()` should be redesigned to differentiate between EOF and real errors. Also `return (error);` is very strange. You either return `bytes_read` or `error`, two semantically different kind of values, how should the caller know which it is?

Comment: Regarding the weird EUR_gread() return: you're right. The reason it's like is is history: the original code was written about 25 years ago by people who didn't believe callers should check return values. We're changing that now by refactoring but we're not there yet.

Comment: I have a better way to demonstrate the issue I'm talking about: a procmon trace that should succeed but fails. I have removed the code because it actually distract from what I'm talking about (I know it isn't perfect, part - and only part - of the reason for this is that I edited it for clarity and left maybe a bit too many things out. But the code itself isn't what I'm asking for: I'm asking about what could explain the OS behavior).